# Trouble in coding a linear regression

Tags: python, linear-regression

i'm training on the data iris.
I try some linear regression, but one of the version i use seems not working.
Can someone explain me why ?
Not working expression :

```
Y4 = iris_versicolor['sepal_width']
X4 = iris_versicolor[['petal_width']]
X4 = sm.add_constant(X4)
moindreCareCas4 = sm.OLS(Y4, X4).fit() # OLS = Ordinary Least Square 
a4,b4 = moindreCareCas4.params['petal_width'],moindreCareCas4.params['intercept']

print(moindreCareCas4.params)

plt.plot(iris_versicolor.sepal_width,iris_versicolor.petal_width, "o")
plt.plot(np.arange(4),[a4*x+b4 for x in np.arange(4)])
plt.xlabel("petal_width")
plt.ylabel("sepal_width")
plt.show()
```

The linear regression is on top of the point cloud by far

Working expression :

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from sklearn import linear_model
from sklearn.metrics import mean_squared_error, r2_score

# Create linear regression object
regr = linear_model.LinearRegression()

# Train the model using the training sets
regr.fit(iris_versicolor[['sepal_width']], iris_versicolor[['petal_width']])

# Make predictions using the testing set
iris_versicolor_petal_width_pred = regr.predict(iris_versicolor[['sepal_width']])

# The coefficients
print('Coefficients: \n', regr.coef_)
# The mean squared error
print('Mean squared error: %.2f'
      % mean_squared_error(iris_versicolor[['petal_width']], iris_versicolor_petal_width_pred))
# The coefficient of determination: 1 is perfect prediction
print('Coefficient of determination: %.2f'
      % r2_score(iris_versicolor[['petal_width']], iris_versicolor_petal_width_pred))

# Plot outputs
plt.scatter(iris_versicolor[['sepal_width']], iris_versicolor[['petal_width']],  color='black')
plt.plot(iris_versicolor[['sepal_width']], iris_versicolor_petal_width_pred, color='blue', linewidth=3)

plt.xticks(())
plt.yticks(())

plt.show()
```

The linear regression is in the point cloud, like it has to .

Thanks !

Comment: In the non-working case, `a4` and `b4` are calculated but `a2` and `b2` are used to draw the line fit.  Where do `a2` and `b2` come from?

Comment: it appears the standard way to introduce a non-zero intercept term for the OLS line fit is `X4 = sm.add_constant(X4)` (ref: https://www.statsmodels.org/stable/examples/notebooks/generated/ols.html )

Comment: @AbbeGijly thanks for the comments,  
a2 and b2 was a typo i change. I change: 
```X4 = X4.copy()
X4['intercept'] = 1.``` 
by  
```X4 = sm.add_constant(X4``` 
but same result:/